# Change scroll axis on mobile devices (touch)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, touch

I have a container that can be scrolled through horizontally. This was done by rotating the container by 90 degrees.
This is however only a visual workaround: the *visual* horizontal scrolling is done by *physical* vertical scrolling. On mobile devices this is very counter-intuitive.

Is there any way to manipulate the scrolling behaviour so that the container can be scrolled through with horizontal touch gestures?

[image: The scrollable container is a high vertical container that's been rotated by 90 degrees.]

Here is a simplified demonstration of the container:

```css
.item {
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.container {
  background: yellow;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe pull out the transform into another section and wrap it in a media query? Then only devices larger than a set width scroll sideways.

Comment: Forgot to mention I have multiple of these containers above each other, so horizontal scrolling would be better from a UI standpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using transform, actualy place the elements side by side in a flex container.

Because you don't want the elements to shrink with the container size you a can set a min-width on the items:

```css
.item {
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width:50px;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  background: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: This solves the scrolling on mobile, but on desktop, this can't be scrolled with the mousewheel. Thinking about using your solution for mobile and mine for desktop, although that surely isn't best practice.